# How to assign value from onDateSet() in a static method

Tags: java, android, static

My problem is that I'm using `DatePickerDialog` to choose date. I want to assign `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg2` to a variable in static method - final cannot be used cause it is not init of this variable, other variable out of `static` `method()` cannot be used too cause it is static method...

```
static method() {
    int variable;

    DatePickerDialog ... {
        onDateSet(...) { 
            variable = arg1; // or smething like this
        }
    }
}
```

How to get `arg1` visible in my `static` `method()` or create something like `getArgs()`?

Comment: declare a global static variable

Comment: I don't know if you could pass variable as a parameter of this static method.